# Solving the determinant of a $5\times 5$ given trace, eigen values and algebraic multiplicity

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, self-learning

> If $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix with trace 15 and if 2 and 3 are eigenvalues of A, each with algebraic multiplicity 2, then the determinant of A is equal to ?

I am preparing for an examination and this question popped up.

I have never solved the determinant of a matrix given its trace, eigenvalues and algebraic multiplicity and I have looked everywhere to find a relation.

What I do know is

Trace of a matrix = sum of the eigen values

Determinant of a matrix = product of eigen values

How are these concepts connected and how do I solve this question?

**EDIT**

Okay so I think I figured out the answer.

Algebraic multiplicity basically means the number of times the eigenvalues are repeated so in this situation the 4 of the 5 eigen values are:

$$2,2,3,3$$

Trace = sum(eigenvalues)

Therefore
$$ 4+6+\lambda = 15 ; \ \lambda = 5$$

Therefore the determinant is simply the product of these eigenvalues

$$ |A| = 180$$

Thanks to everyone in the comments that helped me out. I can't believe I was toiling over such a simple question :)

I shall now go hid in my shell.

Comment: the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and you know four of the five eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) and the trace, so how do you get the missing fith eigenvalue?

Comment: Hello :) Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalues unequal to 2 or 3. We know, there is exactly one and it has multiplicity 1. (Why?) Since the trace is 15, we get $15=2\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+1\cdot \lambda$.

Comment: @LukasHeger Sorry but I don't how to find the fifth eigenvalue. I don't have any knowledge on multiplicity and its relation with either trace or eigenvalues

Comment: @Jochen how did you arrive at that equation?

Comment: The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues (with multiplicity). The determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues (with multiplicity). You know the trace and four of the five summands that give you the trace, so *basic arithmetic* should tell you how to figure out what the fifth summand (that is, the missing eigenvalue) is. Once you know all five eigenvalues, you can figure out the determinant, again with *simple arithmetic*.